# How do i create a chat widget embed script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built a chat application(React) similar to ChatBot.com(LiveChat) and I am trying to create an embed script that people could include on their site.

Live example: you can see right side bottom corner chat widget.
https://www.chatbot.com/integrations/livechat/

Please how do I achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Please include your minimalistic reproducible example into your question, at least its source-code, because links die out over time.

Comment: hey, you may not have gone through the question, it doesn't need a source code, it's asking about how to convert any React application into the embedded script.

Comment: You have a live example. I presume it has a source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate [Tawk.to](https://www.tawk.to/?utm_source=tawk-messenger&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=referral&utm_term=610581a8d6e7610a49aded96), it is very easy to integrate all you have to do it to add the code you give you after you signup. And you can also customise some of the things on the chatbot.